# How do I stop text from moving after animation is completed?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am constructing my website and thought a text reveal animation would be cool. The text reveal animation works, but the text slides to the right unintentionally after the text has been revealed. Any idea on a fix for this?

I have made a Code Pen here: https://codepen.io/JoelEXE/pen/mYbMoX

```css
@keyframes text-reveal {
    0%{width: 0%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    20%{width: 20%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    50%{width: 50%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    80%{width: 80%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    100%{width: 100%; margin-left: 25vw;}
}

.image-bg-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-image: yes;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.reveal-heading-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: text-reveal 5s linear;
}

.image-bg-section h1 {
    font-size: 550%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 45vh;
}
```

```html
            <section class = "image-bg-section">
                <div class = "reveal-heading-container">
                    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: why the margin-left in the animation since it's the same value everytime?

Comment: I don't know, I'm new to this

Comment: try to remove it then, it's useless and probably creating the issue

Comment: No it doesn't work. I just realised I added that in to center the text too

Comment: you don't have to add it inside the animation, add it outside

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-left=25vw` makes the margin from the left side of the screen to the left side of the first letter grow smaller as the screen gets bigger.  Instead, put it in the `h1` css selector.

```css
@keyframes text-reveal {
    0%{width: 0%;}
    20%{width: 20%;}
    50%{width: 50%;}
    80%{width: 80%;}
    100%{width: 100%;}
}

.image-bg-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-image: yes;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.reveal-heading-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: text-reveal 5s linear;
}

.image-bg-section h1 {
    font-size: 550%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 45vh;
}
```

```html
            <section class = "image-bg-section">
                <div class = "reveal-heading-container">
                    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
```

```css
@keyframes text-reveal {
    0%{width: 0%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    20%{width: 20%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    50%{width: 50%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    80%{width: 80%; margin-left: 25vw;}
    100%{width: 100%; margin-left: 25vw;}
}

.image-bg-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-image: yes;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.reveal-heading-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: text-reveal 5s linear;
}

.image-bg-section h1 {
    font-size: 550%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 45vh;
    margin-left:25vw;
}
```

```html
            <section class = "image-bg-section">
                <div class = "reveal-heading-container">
                    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: It still moves though, the `.reveal-heading-container` is centered horizontally through `margin: 0 auto;`. when the container resizes to 100%, the right side will start padding out to the left in order to keep it centered.